# Java Replace All?

Tags: java, replaceall

I´m trying to replace some characters in my string but it isnt working. Can you please help me?

My code is:

```
String test = "ABC?!";
test = test.replaceAll("\\?","");
test= test.replaceAll("\\!, "");
```

Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: "It isn't working" doesn't give us any information. If you don't need regex, use the `replace(String, String)` method instead.

Comment: This `test.replaceAll("\\!, "");` will never work, you're not closing double quotes, try `test.replaceAll("\\!", ""); instead`

Comment: `replace("?","").replace("!","")`

Comment: I think you want to replace `?` and `!` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `str.replaceAll("[?!]", "");`